# ¿Porqué se desalinean elementos de un listview?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, adapter

estaba realizando un listview para la vista de opciones y al momento de ejecutarlo me sale desviado el contenido.
No entiendo porqué :c

Los elementos del item que se desalinean son **item_title** y **item_desc**

ya chequé si son los string que guarde con espacios extras, pero estan bien, sin problemas y justemnte son usando esos 2 ultimos textos, porque cuando invierto el orden de los items y se desalinean los 4

**Imagen del resultado del listview en celular**
 [image: Resultado de vista en dispositivo]

**Activity donde se encuentra el listview**

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
        setTitle(R.string.title_settings)
        setToolbar()

        findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_settings).adapter = SettingsAdapter(ArrayList<Settings>()
            .apply {
                add(Settings(1, getString(R.string.update_user), getString(R.string.update_user_desc), R.drawable.ic_avatar))
                add(Settings(2, getString(R.string.notice_privacy), getString(R.string.notice_privacy_desc), R.drawable.ic_avatar))
                add(Settings(4, getString(R.string.about), getString(R.string.about_desc), R.drawable.ic_avatar))
                add(Settings(3, getString(R.string.logout), getString(R.string.logout_desc), R.drawable.ic_avatar))
            })
    }
    @SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
    private fun setToolbar() { }
}
```

**Adapter para el listview**

```
class SettingsAdapter(private  var settings: ArrayList<Settings>) : BaseAdapter()
{
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    override fun getView(pos: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false).apply {
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_title).text = settings[pos].title
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_desc).text = settings[pos].desc
            findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.item_icon).setImageResource(settings[pos].icon)
            setOnClickListener {
            }
        }
}
class Settings (var id:Long, var title: String, var desc: String, var icon: Int)
```

**Layout del activity donde esta el listview**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_settings"
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/bar" >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Layout del item para el listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/item_container_icon" >
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/item_icon"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_title"
              style="@style/Text"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_container_icon" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.125"/>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/item_after_tittle"  />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_desc"
              android:textAlignment="center"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/item_title"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/item_after_tittle" />
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/item_extra" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: puede ser debido a que estás centrando el texto de `item_title` y `item_desc`, `android:textAlignment="center"`

Comment: pero porqué unidamente sucede con los ultimamos dos y no también con los primeros?

Comment: De hecho los primeros dos, si te fijas bien, también están desalineados, intenta usar `textStart ` en vez de `center`

Comment: Listo, ya probé @ElMicke ya probé y si era eso, ademas era los constraints que tenia con el borde de la pantalla en la parte derecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar :

```
android:textAlignment="textStart"
```

para alinear los textos al inicio, en lugar de:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

---

Aunque posiblemente el texto pudiera contener espacios, usa el método [trim()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/trim.html) para eliminarlos:

```
...
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_title).text = settings[pos].title.trim()
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_desc).text = settings[pos].desc.trim()
...
```